# Node: async.foreach fails silently when error is uncaught exception is thrown

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, promise

I'm wrapping some async executed 'child'-functions in an async.forEach construct (from the great lib: https://github.com/caolan/async)

When one of these child-functions fails with an uncaught exception the entire node-process hangs. (since a callback is never returned to the async.forEach construct, async.forEach still thinks a child-function is busy)

However I would have thought at least the thrown exception would bubble up, since I'm not catching it anywhere. Is there a way to configure how async.forEach handles these exceptions? It's really hard programming against this.

Comment: What does your code look like? What's throwing this exception? (your code, or some other module)

Comment: I'm more asking generically. The point is these child-functions can be hot-plugged/swapped in some sort of CMS-fashion. Technically I could wrap client code called in these child-functions in try/catch-blocks and return proper callback(err) myself, etc. But when defining these functions I don't want to have to concern myself with error handling, etc, just functional flow. An occasional mistake in such a  function should not halt the entire system. Instead I want the (heavily tested) infrastructure calling the configured function to handle the thrown error.

Comment: Not sure if my explanation was clear. Anyway, I've come across Q (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which is based on promises instead of callbacks. It looks like a well-documented feature that thrown exceptions can automatically be converted to (in promise speak) promise.rejections. Freeing the 'child'-functions from the 100% need of catching all errors correctly.

Comment: Same issue with `async.series`. Uncaught exceptions silently kill the process. Your workaround using Q works well.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. For future reference:

OK so I basically had this:

```
var async = require("async");
var cb = function(){
   //denote done to async.foreach
}
async.forEach(defaultFunctions,function(defaultFunc,cb){   
  defaultFunc(cb);
},callback);
```

The problem was that when a certain defaultFunction throws an uncaught exception, the exception is swallowed by [`async.forEach`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback). Moreover there's no way to catch it in the calling context.

The result is severe: complete halt of the parent node-process, without any trance what's causing it.

In the called context (i.e: the defaultFunction that throws the exception) I could of course meticulously try to catch all exceptions, but these functions are hot-pluggable, possibly ranging in the hundreds in the end and I don't want to burden each of these functions with 100% full-proof error-handling.

A solution I've found is to use promises (using the Q library -> github.com/kriskowal/q ) to wrap the functions in:

```
var async = require("async")
var Q = require("q");
var cb = function(){
   //denote done to async.foreach
}
async.forEach(defaultFunctions,function(defaultFunc,cb){   
  var obj = {
    defaultFunc: defaultFunc
  } 
  return Q.ncall(obj.defaultFunc,obj)
    .then(function(result){
       return cb() ;
    }fail(function(err){
       return cb(err); //ANY thrown uncaught error in obj.defaultFunc will get 
                       //caught and changed to a correct callback as needed
                       //for async.forEach
    }
},callback);
```

Of course, now I realize async.foreach can be done trivially with Q.promises instead but that's another story...

Comment: Weird.  I'm not able to reproduce the async problem with a simple example where one of the `defaultFunctions` throws an exception.  Also, why didn't you use `async.parallel(defaultFunctions, cb);` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: hmmm, weird indeed.. As for the `forEach` that was the method that immediately solved by case from quickly glancing at the examples.  I realize now `parallel` would work equally well. I'm going to refactor/test if `parallel` doesnt' have the issue I was experiencing.